# Extending a hard-to-access exhaust fan duct

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan

Just pulled out an old bathroom fan. It was screwed to a 12-inch-long piece of non-flexible duct (so it came out with the fan casing). The end of the duct is buried in the insulation up in the attic. I can reach it with my hand but cannot imagine wrapping duct tape around it when I replace the missing non-flexible duct with a flexible equivalent (or at least it will be really tricky). I don't have access to the attic.

Is there a "pro trick" or a snap-on of some sort I could use to attach the new flexible duct to non-flexible one, given the access constraints?

The diameter of the duct is 4 inches.

Comment: Non-flexible is better for moving air. Is the piece in the attic flexible so that you could pull it closer to you to make the connection?

Comment: @user20127 unfortunately it is not - afraid to touch it to sever a connection even further in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a junction that would snap to an existing pipe.

However, with it being only a foot away, I think you could attach some flex and persistently stick small bits of foil tape around the joint. (Go the long way... not the circumference.) You may have to cut a few short nips in the flex to help you get it over the hard pipe.

Alternately, you could cut the ceiling, hard pipe it perfectly, then patch. (But nobody likes that... even drywallers.)